# Sequence of integer square roots

Tags: code-golf, number, sequence

Let's define a sequence of integer square roots. First, a(1) = 1. Then, a(n) is the smallest positive integer **not seen before** such that

```
sqrt(a(n) + sqrt(a(n-1) + sqrt(... + sqrt(a(1)))))
```

is an integer. Some  examples:

a(2) is 3 because it's the smallest integer such that `sqrt(a(2) + sqrt(a(1))) = sqrt(a(2) + 1)` is integer, and 3 hasn't occured in the sequence before.

a(3) is 2 because it's the smallest integer such that `sqrt(a(3) + sqrt(a(2) + sqrt(a(1)))) = sqrt(a(3) + 2)` is integer, and 2 hasn't occured in the  sequence before.

a(4) is 7 because `sqrt(a(4) + 2)` is integer. We couldn't have a(4) = 2 because 2 already occured in our sequence.

Write a program or function that given a parameter *n* returns a sequence of numbers a(1) to a(n).

The sequence starts 1,3,2,7,6,13,5, ....

<sup>Source of this sequence is from [this Math.SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2469058/a-n-is-the-smallest-positive-integer-number-such-that-sqrta-n-sqrta-n-1).</sup>

---

A plot of the first 1000 elements in the sequence:

[image: plot]

Comment: **[:'-(](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C3%2C2%2C7%2C6%2C13%2C5&language=english&go=Search)**

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder That just makes it interesting!

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Yeah I agree it's so bad you can't just copy-paste the formula...

Comment: Can we have 0-indexed input?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer No. When you get _n_ as input you should return or print a list of a(1) to a(n). In other words, the first _n_ numbers in the sequence. There is no 'indexing'.

Comment: Are errors caused by floating point inaccuracies acceptable for very large inputs?

Comment: @Zgarb I guess it's too late now already... Fine... Use floating point 'answers'.

Comment: * *the want to play connect the dots intensifies* *

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 80 bytes

```python
s=[]
exec'x=q=1\nwhile(x in s)+q%1:x+=1;q=(v+x)**.5\nv=q;s+=x,;'*input()
print s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hc1LDoMgEADQPacgJI18GiOabkrmJNWVJZGkGUFQp6ennwu8F99lWbGv8/r0sAkhaobHxDz5uSFIYEc8l/DyknhAnpVJF3snA9YlkIchpXV7G/GA5LIBurpGB4x7kYrFLWDhuX7Rv8d/hx6qZQPru@4D)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 87 bytes

```python
t,=s=1,
for n in~-input()*s:
 while(n in s)+(t+n)**.5%1:n+=1
 s+=n,;t=(t+n)**.5
print s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Pck7CoAwDADQvafIIvSnUEEEJcdRWpC0NBFx8eoVF9f3yi0x09iaeGQMXu25AkGip09UTtHG8qLgiunY9OfAxmlxZKwdpi4s5DAoYIfkV8F/VKmJBLi1@QU)

-3 thanks to [Mr. Xcoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59487/mr-xcoder).
-5 thanks to [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs).

Comment: [92 bytes](https://tio.run/##PclNCoMwEAbQfU4xm0L@FCJIwTLHqTggn8EZKW68elo3fdtXT1s2DK1ZZuWS3bztJCS4OkE9zIeokyNwcfRZZH17/JI0JG8JIcZ@fJQJ6X5NjPwy/o@ru8BIW3t@AQ) -> `while n in s or(t+n)**.5%1>0` -> `while(n in s)+(t+n)**.5%1`

Comment: [87 bytes](https://tio.run/##Pck7CoAwDADQvafIIvSnUEEEJcdRWpC0NBFx8eoVF9f3yi0x09iaeGQMXu25AkGip09UTtHG8qLgiunY9OfAxmlxZKwdpi4s5DAoYIfkV8F/VKmJBLi1@QU)

Comment: @ovs clever one

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>103</s> 87 bytes

Horribly inefficient, but does not rely on floating point arithmetic. Here `a(x) = sqrt(f(x)+a(x-1))` is a helper sequence, that simplifies the computation.

```hs
a 0=0
a x=[k|k<-[1..],m<-[k^2-a(x-1)],m>0,notElem m$f<$>[1..x-1]]!!0
f x=(a x)^2-a(x-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYy7CoNAEEV7v@IKFgqz4iOJIGqXrxADS7JLZF01UcEi/74ZmzSZ28xlzpmnXIwaBuckkjrxJPa6NR9TiTaN444sL@aWCRnuIo24NwmN03odlIUNdBU0B8e3rvP9xNOsh/wj@inOyn5EjfndjysCWDlDH07ReUJgeU7b8MC0rfO2QpdASjllVNCF0pzOBwMs6rWp8a4waciSkYyTc06U42/cFw)

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>30</s> 27 bytes

```
lXHiq:"`@ymH@+X^1\+}8MXHx@h
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/PyfCI7PQSinBoTLXw0E7Is4wRrvWwjfCo8Ih4/9/cwA) Or see a [graphical display](http://matl.suever.net/?code=lXHiq%3A%22%60%40ymH%40%2BX%5E1%5C%2B%7D8MXHx%40h%5D%5D%27o%27%26XG&inputs=60&version=20.4.2) (takes a while; times out for inputs exceeding approximately `60`).

#### Explanation

```
l          % Push 1. This is the array that holds the sequence, initialized to
           % a single term. Will be extended with subsequent terms
XH         % Copy into clipboard H, which holds the latest result of the 
           % "accumulated" square root
iq:"       % Input n. Do the following n-1 times
  `        %   Do...while
    @      %     Push interaton index k, starting at 1. This is the candidate
           %     to being the next term of the sequence
    y      %     Push copy of array of terms found so far
    m      %     Ismbmer? True if k is in the array
    H      %     Push accumulated root
    @+     %     Add k
    X^     %     Square root
    1\     %     Modulo 1. This gives 0 if k gives an integer square root
    +      %     Add. Gives nonzero if k is in the array or doesn't give an
           %     integer square root; that is, if k is invalid.
           %   The body of the do...while loop ends here. If the top of the
           %   stack is nonzero a new iteration will be run. If it is zero that
           %   means that the current k is a new term of the sequence
  }        %   Finally: this is executed after the last iteration, right before
           %   the loop is exited
    8M     %     Push latest result of the square root
    XH     %     Copy in clipboard K
    x      %     Delete
    @      %     Push current k
    h      %     Append to the array
           % End do...while (implicit)
           % Display (implicit)
```

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, 104 bytes

```
(s=f={i=1};Do[t=1;While[!IntegerQ[d=Sqrt[t+s[[i]]]]||!f~FreeQ~t,t++];f~(A=AppendTo)~t;s~A~d;i++,#-1];f)&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcnBCoJAEADQX0mCUNbAPS8DCRF0Swo6DB6WdtSFXG2dWza/vvmub7Q80GjZv2zqIeULdPD1oH/mPCGDNs/Bvwmza2DqKTbo4P6JjKwWRN9u1jXr5BKJGuGSlWpNJ3kN9TxTcI@pEDaL1OKMV6rcH/X2xSHdog@8O/Woq6pNfw)

The sequence of the square roots is also very interesting...
and outputs a similar pattern

> 1,2,2,3,3,4,3,5,3,6,4,4,5,4,6,5,5,6,6,7,4,7,5,7,6,8,4,8,5,8,6,9,5,9,6,10,5,10,6,11,5,11,6,12,6,13,6,14,7,7,8,7,9,7,10,7,11,7,12,7,13,7,14,8,8,9,8,10...

[image]

also here are the differences of the main sequence

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>117</s> <s>115</s> <s>112</s> <s>102</s> <s>99</s> 87 bytes

```python
t,=r=1,;exec"x=1\nwhile(t+x)**.5%1or x in r:x+=1\nr+=x,;t=(t+x)**.5;"*~-input();print r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Pco7CoAwDADQq5SCYD@KFVwsuYmbFCxILCFiXLx6xcX5vXLzduBYK3sgCD4mSasWCAteW95Ty06Mtf3UhIOUqIyKZnGfkwPxkeEvUduny1hObk0slJEV1ToOLw)

Used the `t=(t+x)**.5` logic from [Erik's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/145152/38592)

Comment: [99 bytes](https://tio.run/##FctLCsMgEADQqwyBgp9pqYFuIt4kG02ECOlEBkOnm1zd0rd/9du2g8beOTj0WfIySHAzfbayZ@C8nktWe3ynNULENKlokzbm8UK2SlDrmzsYBAoBT2L/lW0Q9IO57oXq2ZT2lQs14N7H5w8).

Comment: @JonathanFrech Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>138</s> <s>105</s> 99 bytes

```r
function(n){for(i in 1:n){j=1
while(Reduce(function(x,y)(y+x)^.5,g<-c(T,j))%%1|j%in%T)j=j+1
T=g}
T}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/TyNPszotv0gjUyEzT8HQCsjLsjXkKs/IzEnVCEpNKU1O1YArrdCp1NSo1K7QjNMz1Um30U3WCNHJ0tRUVTWsyVLNzFMN0cyyzdI25AqxTa/lCqn9n6ZhaKj5HwA)

*-33 bytes using [Tfeld's clever `sqrt()%%1` trick](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/145149/67312) in the while loop*

*-6 bytes using T instead of F*

#### original answer, 138 bytes:

```r
function(n,l={}){g=function(L)Reduce(function(x,y)(y+x)^.5,L,0)
for(i in 1:n){T=1
while(g(c(l,T))!=g(c(l,T))%/%1|T%in%l)T=T+1
l=c(l,T)}
l}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcmxCsIwEIDhPU8Rh8AdjdoMLuK9QSfJ7BKTGjiuUCy2xDx7HIRuP98/t6Rvx5YWCe88CYhlKhXLSDsNeI/PJUTYZbUbwtat@Dhd7GB7VGmaIess2l0FiyenPq/MEUYIwNYjHmhPczbu600Ww@jJd04x/VdVXFsC12P7AQ)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES7), <s>89</s> <s>82</s> <s>77</s> 76 bytes

```js
i=>(g=k=>(s=(++n+k)**.5)%1||u[n]?g(k):i--?[u[n]=n,...g(s,n=0)]:[])(n=0,u=[])
```

#### Demo

```js
let f =

i=>(g=k=>(s=(++n+k)**.5)%1||u[n]?g(k):i--?[u[n]=n,...g(s,n=0)]:[])(n=0,u=[])

console.log(JSON.stringify(f(10)))
```

#### Formatted and commented

```js
i => (                             // given i = number of terms to compute
  u = [],                          // u = array of encountered values
  g = p =>                         // g = recursive function taking p = previous square root
    (s = (++n + p) ** .5) % 1      // increment n; if n + p is not a perfect square,
    || u[n] ?                      // or n was already used:
      g(p)                         //   do a recursive call with p unchanged
    :                              // else:
      i-- ?                        //   if there are other terms to compute:
        [u[n] = n, ...g(s, n = 0)] //     append n, set u[n] and call g() with p = s, n = 0
      :                            //   else:
        []                         //     stop recursion
  )(n = 0)                         // initial call to g() with n = p = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 21 bytes

```
!¡oḟȯΛ±sFo√+Som:`-N;1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASkA1v9odXNr//8hwqFv4bifyK/Om8Kxc0Zv4oiaK1NvbTpgLU47Mf///zEwMA)

#### How?

```
!¡oḟȯΛ±sFo√+Som:`-N;1    Function that generates a list of prefixes of the sequence and indexes into it
                   ;1    The literal list [1]
 ¡                       Iterate the following function, collecting values in a list
  oḟȯΛ±sFo√+Som:`-N        This function takes a prefix of the sequence, l, and returns the next prefix.
                `-N      Get all the natural numbers that are not in l.
            Som:         Append l in front each of these numbers, generates all possible prefixes.
    ȯΛ±sFo√+               This predicate tests if sqrt(a(n) + sqrt(a(n-1) + sqrt(... + sqrt(a(1))))) is an integer.
        F                Fold from the left
         o√+             the composition of square root and plus
       s                 Convert to string
    ȯΛ±                  Are all the characters digits, (no '.')
  oḟ                     Find the first list in the list of possible prefixes that satisfies the above predicate
!                        Index into the list
```